# API Question on relationships standard and custom

Tags: soql, rest-api, sobject

I have a query (below) but I want to connect to account and query name of the account.

I have tried doing account.Name, account__r.Name but I get errors.

```
select Customer_ID__c,  Product2Id, Sales_Channel__c, PurchaseDate, Price, Transaction_Number__c, TRXID__c  from asset
```

How do I query a standard object across objects with a relationship ?

I know with a custom object you can do Account__r.Name but how do you do that with a standard object ?

Comment: `Account.Name` is correct because it's a standard replationship between standard objects. You should [edit] your question to include the error message you're geting, verbatim.

Comment: I would give you the error but apparently it worked this time TY for your help. Write out a answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For child-parent relationships, there are two possible ways to use it to reference data on the parent record. It depends on whether the relationship field is a standard field (one provided by Salesforce, like `OwnerId` on pretty much every object, or `AccountId` on things like `Opportunity` and `Asset`) or a custom field (one ending in `__c`).

The rule of thumb for standard relationships is to simply drop the "Id" part. E.g. instead of using `AccountId`, the query is `SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Asset`.

For custom relationships, we simply change `__c` to `__r` (which I like to think of as meaning it's a ***r***elated object).

In this case, since you're using the standard relationship between `Asset` and `Account`, you'd reference it as `Account.Name`. That goes for Apex as well as querying through the REST API.

Be aware that this is correct for child-parent queries. A parent-child subquery has a similar, but different, set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
SELECT Id, Account.Name FROM Asset
```

Account.Name should work. Kindly share your error if you are still getting it. It's the same between all standard object relationships between them.